# IIS 10 / ARR 3 / Websocket /

Tags: iis, websocket, reverse-proxy, arr

I have an IIS 10 with ARR 3.0 and websockets

If I'm using directly iis, my websockets works great.
The websocket's address is like ws://IP_SERVER:PORT/ws/XXXX

If I'm using the same iis (and same site with a rewrite url rule) as reverse proxy, my websocket connects and disconnects forever.

The websocket's address is like ws://DOMAIN:PORT/ws/XXXX

The Url Rewrite configuration is:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:1880/{R:1}" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you every figure this out?